# JavaFX to connect and execute db2 commands

Tags: java, db2, javafx-8, processbuilder

JavaFx - I need to execute the db2cw.bat driver and then

1. Change directory
2. Execute .cmd file
3. Execute db2 EXPORT command
4. Once Export processed, Close the window

I used Processbuilder in my code. db2cw.bat is opened successfully from the directory `cwd` and `dbc` command executed to connect to DB2. But the next command fails with IO exception. How should i pass the Export command to the command line?

```
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
```

Code

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(cmd); // path to db2cw.bat
        list.add(dbc); // path to .cmd file for DB2 connection
        list.add(exp); // path to db2EXPORT command
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(list); 
        Process p = null;
        builder.directory(new File(cwd));
        try {
            p = builder.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //get stdin of shell
        BufferedWriter p_stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

        try {
            p_stdin.write(exp);
            System.out.println(cwd);
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Export Error");
        }

        try {
            p_stdin.write("exit");
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Exit Error");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be a LOT easier to just execute the query in your application and then just write the comma/tab/etc. delimited text file directly?

Comment: I was successful with the DB2 connection using JDBC. But in case of EXPORT and IMPORT commands, i could not execute them as a query. so looking to use the DB2 CLP for EXPORT and IMPORT